# YUM: How to prevent EPEL from upgrading packages installed from other repos?

Tags: yum, upgrade, repository

I would like to leave EPEL enabled and configure it to allow updating only the packages that were installed from EPEL itself in the first place (packages which were manually installed from EPEL because of specific needs). **Is there a yum conf directive to allow this?**

- CentOS 6.4
- Yum 3.2.29

Comment: It should just work like this since EPEL packages never include packages that are in base.

Comment: However, EPEL can conflict with local and other third-party repos, such as ATrpms, RPMforge, or other vendor-specific repos.

Comment: Yes, @JamesSneeringer: in my case, Virtualmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `yum-plugin-priorities` package, which lets you add a `priority` parameter to your repo files. The priority range is 1-99, with 99 being the default. A lower number means higher priority.

Since 99 is the default, and you want to give EPEL even less priority, you'll need to increase the priority (lower number) of all other repos to ensure EPEL doesn't override them. For example:

```
[epel]
priority=99

[base]
priority=50

[local]
priority=25
```

I'm doing exactly this to ensure my local repo gets priority, and it works great.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have package XYZ which is v0.44 and was installed from ART. If EPEL is enabled, 'yum upgrade' will offer to update XYZ with v0.48 from EPEL. ART is priority=1 and EPEL is priority=99.

Comment: Is the priorities plug-in enabled? It should be by default, but you can double-check in `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf`. There should be a line that says `enabled=1`.

Comment: it wasn't, thanks. but now I have "77 packages excluded due to repository priority protections". how do i find out which ones were excluded? before enabling it i had nothing to upgrade.

Comment: Run `yum` with debug level 3 (`-d 3`). The default appears to be level 2, which only shows the summary. At level 3, it will show which packages were excluded, and from which repo(s).